# Maintain my patches in git repo

Tags: git, patch

I am just learning how to use git and would like to follow a project. So I clone the project and no I have the most new code.

If I want to add a patch (or more) to that code, what is the best way to do that (and run `make` and `make install`) and still be able to `git pull` from the master repo without creating a conflict?

I have tried making a branch, but I'm not sure if this is the right way.

I'd just like to be able to keep up with new code in master, but be able to apply my own patches as new versions are pushed.

I'd like to know where I can learn how to do this, but I'm not sure what to google for.

Comment: What do you mean by your patches? When using a version control system, you don't need patches, because your commits act like those patches

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maintaining custom patches on third party code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397188/maintaining-custom-patches-on-third-party-code)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably looking for `git rebase`: Create a local branch from the remote tracking branch and invoke `git config branch.mylocalbranch.rebase true` (where 'mylocalbranch' is the name of your local branch). Now you can make your local patches and commit them. Everytime you fetch updates with `git pull` your local modifications are 'rebased' (applied on top of what you've just pulled).

Be careful not to push your local modifications (e.g. the HEAD of your local branch) to the remote as this is probably not what you want. See `man git-rebase` for further details.

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe, I am guessing branching is indeed what you want. You want on your own branch, you can push to the server, you can merge with whatever happens on other branches

Best way to learn branching is by trying it a few times, make conflicts and resolve them after a merge and you'll get the hang of it. You can start [here](http://book.git-scm.com/3_basic_branching_and_merging.html)