# How to manage the open source projects patches which can't push to upstream?

Tags: git, open-source, linux-kernel, kernel, patch

I'm working on a open source project. Now I finished a few patches which are relevant to the company business and I can't push these patches to upstream.

So I have to keep these patches on my local git repository. I have to pull the new patches from upstream and resolve the conflicts with my patches.

Anyone have my similar experience and how to work with it comfortably?

Update:
Just like if I have several patches can't be accept by Linux Kernel because these patches are unfriendly to the kernel. I have to do daily kernel building and I don't want to type by hand everyday. Is there exists any tools to help me?

Comment: Why can't you push? do you have an error description or something?

Comment: Is the project on GitHub?

Comment: If the project is open source, can you tell us which project it is?  Maybe we can find out how that particular project wants to handle submissions.

Comment: Maybe the patch contains some internal secrets the op is not allowed to submit to the public?

Comment: Thank you for your enthusiastic help, but it isn't the project problem. Just because of my patches contains the unfriendly business binding.

Comment: In one word, I shouldn't and can't push it to upstream.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maintaining custom patches on third party code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397188/maintaining-custom-patches-on-third-party-code)

Answer (score 6):

I am somewhat surprised that the answers so far don't seem to take into account two things:

1. Not all modifications done by programmers is intended for or suitable for submission to an open source project.
2. Even when it is, if there is an update to the repository while your working on your code, you very often want to merge those changes into your working copy.

The good thing is that since you are working with a decent version control software is not usually that difficult to do what you need.  I'm a subversion guy (due to company policy) so I don't specifically know about GIT but after reading [this wiki article](http://genomewiki.ucsc.edu/index.php/Resolving_merge_conflicts_in_Git), it seems pretty much the same deal.  You don't have to apply the patches again as long as you fit the files in your local repository.  You can update the local copy with the patches already applied!

Your custom code probably touches a very small fraction of the repository code.  It's likely that most changes in the repository will not touch the same code you've touched.  You will simply need to use the git pull command to download all the updated code.  When the sections you have touched are changed on the repository, git will do it's best to merge those changes.  The only time you have to hand edit files is she git detects a conflict that it can't resolve.  The article I mentioned, earlier talks about this.

You may use your favorite text editor but actually it is quite convenient to use a 3-way merge tool in this case.  [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) is one such tool for Linux but I'm sure there are many out there.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible workflow.

**Initial setup**

```
git clone --origin 'upstream' http://example.com/project.git
cd project
git checkout master
git checkout -b patched
# make changes
git add --all
git commit -m 'internal patches'
```

**New upstream changes**

```
git checkout master
git pull upstream
git checkout patched
git rebase master
```

**References:**

- [rolf@Supenta: Git: How to consistently maintain local patches](http://blog.supenta.com/2014/05/15/git-how-to-consistently-maintain-local-patches/)
- [Maintaining a local patch set with git - Tony Finch](http://fanf.livejournal.com/128282.html)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly before making changes to the project-

```
  1. create a branch
  2. Change to that branch for any changes you make
  3. To pull the new patches from the upstream revert back to the master branch and then git pull.
```

The commands to create the branch and change are as follows

```
1. $ git branch <branch name>           // To create a new branch
2. $ git checkout <branch name>         // To change to the branch
3. $ git checkout master                // To change to the master branch
```

Comment: Is there exists any management system to deal with? Just like if I I have a lot of patches and several projects, it's will be a time-consuming thing to keep my local repository updated.

Comment: As of now I am not using any management system. But as you rightly mentioned there is need for it. I will update once I find a right tool that helps to work on several project

Answer (score -1):

> I'm working on a open source project. Now I finished a few patches which are relevant to the company business and I can't push these patches to upstream.

If you're collaborating on a project in Git, especially if it's open source, people probably won't let you just push anything you want to the upstream repo.  You probably either want to submit your changes in a pull request, or email the patches to one of the project managers.

You can read more about collaborating with other people in Git from these [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book) chapters:

1. [Distributed Workflows](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows)
2. [Contributing to a Project](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Contributing-to-a-Project)

If you're interested, you can also read about [how GitHub uses pull requests](https://help.github.com/categories/63/articles).