# git - maintaining your patches vs proprietary unversioned source

Tags: git, format-patch

I feel like git "should" be able to handle this scenario, I think our case is slightly different than this:
[Maintaining custom patches on third party code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397188/maintaining-custom-patches-on-third-party-code)

Basically our workflow is:

1. Custom patches on proprietary website engine
2. Website has its own upgrade process, overwrites all files
3. Now we have differences introduced in the upgrade, as well as our patches

I do keep a separate repo of their point releases and I'm able to match this against our changes. Right now I patch these in manually.

It seems to me that I would have no way of handling this in a more automated fashion, unless there is an advanced workflow I could be taking advantage of?

Answer (score 0):

One possible workflow would be to commit each update from upstream to a branch (`upstream`), then keep your patch in another specific branch, that you rebase on every upgrade.

Before:

```
* C (upstream)
|
* B
|
| * (patches) patch2
| |
| * patch1
|/
* A
```

After:

```
  * (patches) patch2
  |
  * patch1
 /
* C (upstream)
|
* B
|
* A
```

Comment: I like this approach, but I don't think it's going to work for us, the line numbers and content of what changes shifts too much version-to-version.

For now, my solution is working this out with magit and spacemacs. I diff against our most recent good code vs their updated code.