# Maintaining a fork with patches in master

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I want to maintain a fork with custom functionality added on top of the original code. It is not a contribution to the project itself and won't be merged upstream.

What I want to achieve:

- The GitHub page of the fork should point to the patched version of the project instead of the original one.
- I should be able to easily merge new upstream code while preserving a separate history for my own commits.

My current plan is to have the `upstream/master` branch in the fork repository as `vendor`, from which my own `master` will be branched. Whenever there is a stable release upstream I can pull & push it into the `vendor` branch and than rebase my `master`.

Questions:

1. Is there an easier or cleaner way to achieve the same results?
2. Should I fork via GitHub web-interface and then move `master`, or should I create the repository locally as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15771168/10637894)?

Comment: This seems like a perfectly reasonable workflow. Forking via the GitHub web interface is nice because it provides a pointer to the original project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fork is just a more formal way to link those two GitHub repo.

You don't even need to name upstream/master as "vendor": you can directly rebase your own master branch on top of that remote branch.

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout master
git rebase upstream/master
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach. I guess I should've paid more attention to the git-rebase manpages. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any approach that allows keeping refs to older versions as tags/branches? (eg: changes applied on an older upstream, for rolling back)

Comment: @Edi you can make a tag first, before the rebase: that will keep the previous state referenced.